# How do you make a div vertical but aligned to the bottom left coords of a horizontal div?

Tags: css

A rough sketch is on a fiddle here. Is there a way to make that happen without hardcoded values for the height and width of the div's?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Actss/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `transform-origin` is supposed to help with.

I've looked at your fiddle. Do you need the div's to be absolutely positioned? If not, then setting [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin) to `0 0` is enough to make it work. (I'm supposing this is how you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/Actss/17/ )

Removing the `position: absolute` from the divs guarantees the second `div`'s top-left corner is touching the first `div`'s bottom-left corner. Make the rotation on the second `div` happen at that same point (by using `transform-origin`) and you'll get the effect you want.

Comment: fanstastic. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Don't be sorry. We choose to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the point you are rotating around by using `transform-origin`.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
```

This will rotate the element around the bottom left point. By default this is set to the centre of the element (50% 50%).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Actss/16/)